# Error message when input a character in C

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
int Menu;
while (Menu >= 0)
{
    printf("\n(1) y");
    printf("\n(2) exactness");
    printf("\n(3) x");
    printf("\n\nTo exit press (0).");
    printf("\n\nYour choice: ");
    scanf("%d", &Menu);

        switch (Menu)
        {
        case 0:
            {
                exit (0);
            }
        case 1:
            {
                printf("Please enter a value for y: ");
                break;
            }
        case 2:
            {
                printf("Please enter the exactness for the calculation: ");
                break;
            }
        case 3:
            {
                printf("Please enter a value for x: ");
                break;
            }
        default:
            {
                printf("Wrong input\n");
            }
        }

}

}
```

If I input:

- any number (except 0,1,2, and 3), result is "Wrong input" (CORRECT)
- any symbol, letter or character, result is an infinite loop (WRONG!, this should be "Wrong input" too)

Any idea how to make it works? :) Can someone please correct my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Initialize `Menu` before using, or you will invoke *undefined behavior*.
- Check if reading is successful, and if not remove junk from the stream.
- Add `#include <stdlib.h>` to use the function `exit()`.

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int Menu = 0;
    while (Menu >= 0)
    {
        printf("\n(1) y");
        printf("\n(2) exactness");
        printf("\n(3) x");
        printf("\n\nTo exit press (0).");
        printf("\n\nYour choice: ");
        if (scanf("%d", &Menu) != 1)
        {
            /* read error */
            Menu = 9999; /* assign dummy value */
            scanf("%*s"); /* remove junk */
        }

        switch (Menu)
        {
        case 0:
            {
                exit (0);
            }
        case 1:
            {
                printf("Please enter a value for y: ");
                break;
            }
        case 2:
            {
                printf("Please enter the exactness for the calculation: ");
                break;
            }
        case 3:
            {
                printf("Please enter a value for x: ");
                break;
            }
        default:
            {
                printf("Wrong input\n");
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: You can get rid of all of the curly braces inside the case blocks. They serve no purpose other than to bloat the code.